# React is complaining that I'm causing too many re-renders

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

The `renderDialogue` function should render [Dialogue](https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/props/dialog#types-dismiss) when the window size is less than 654px, otherwise it should update the state of `expandMenu` to `false`. However, React is saying there are too many re-renders. How to solve this?

```js
const [expandMenu, setExpandMenu] = useState(false); 

const handleOpenMenu = () => {
  setExpandMenu(!expandMenu);
};

const renderDialogue = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 654) {
      return (
        <Dialog
          open={expandMenu}
          handler={() => handleOpenMenu()}
          size={"xl"}
          className={"bg-transparent shadow-none "}
        >
          <DialogBody>
            <div className={"relative"}>
              <img
                src={"/imgFolder2/cloud.webp"}
                className={"h-full float-center"}
              />
              <ul className="flex flex-col justify-center h-[75%] gap-5 text-2xl text-center absolute top-[50%] left-[50%] translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%] w-[55%]">
                {NavItems()}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </DialogBody>
        </Dialog>
      );
    } else {
      setExpandMenu(false);
      return <> </>;
    }
  };
```

Here is the `NavItems` function, which iterates through an array of links.

```js
const NavItems = () => {
    return paths.map((path, idx) => (
      <li key={idx}>
        <Link
          href={getPath(idx)}
          className={`text-black block ${
            isSelectedPath(getName(idx, true))
              ? "border-b-4 border-buttonBG"
              : ""
          }`}
          onClick={() => {
            if (window.innerWidth < 654) setExpandMenu(!expandMenu);
          }}
        >
          {getName(idx)}
        </Link>
      </li>
    ));
  };
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your function `NavItems`

Comment: @kingkong.js I added the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your component will never re-render when the window size changes. This means that your if-statement where you display something depending on the window width will only fire on first render. Which probably is fine, but not recommended.

Secondly, your error "too many re-renders" is because you invoke `setExpandMenu` directly in your component. Each time you update your `expandMenu` state, this component will re-render. Then you update it again, so it will re-render again. See the infinite loop here?

Below is a working example of what you want, including updating on window resize. I've added comments to explain what is happening:

```js
    const [expandMenu, setExpandMenu] = useState(false); 
    const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(0)


       useEffect(() => { // This will update your state depending on your window size
        function updateSize() {
        setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth)
          

        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', updateSize);
        updateSize();
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateSize);
      }, []);

      const handleOpenMenu = () => {
        setExpandMenu(!expandMenu);
      };

    const renderDialogue = () => {

        
        if (windowWidth > 654 || expandMenu) {
          return (
            <Dialog
              open={expandMenu}
              handler={() => handleOpenMenu()}
              size={"xl"}
              className={"bg-transparent shadow-none "}
            >
              <DialogBody>
                <div className={"relative"}>
                  <img
                    src={"/imgFolder2/cloud.webp"}
                    className={"h-full float-center"}
                  />
                  <ul className="flex flex-col justify-center h-[75%] gap-5 text-2xl text-center absolute top-[50%] left-[50%] translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%] w-[55%]">
                    {NavItems()}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </DialogBody>
            </Dialog>
          );
        } else {
          // setExpandMenu(false); <--- This line is causing rerenders: Remove it!
          return <> </>;
        }
```